# Chai/Moka -> TypeError: request.get(...).expect is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, tdd, chai

First time with TDD. I'm using the duo Chai/Moka after reading some article online for my NodeJS API.

I already made few dumb test to learn how to use those. Now I want test my API so I created a route :

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('Hello World!')
})
```

I try a test like this :

```
var request = require('superagent')
var expect = require('Chai').expect

[...]

describe('When request baseURL/hello', function(){
    it('should salute you !', function (done) {
      request
      .get(baseURL + '/hello')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res){
        if(err) return done(err)
        done()
      })
    })
  })
```

I have the fail output :

```
TypeError: request.get(...).expect is not a function
```

If I comment the expect line everything is working. I try this route with Postman and I have a 200 status code like expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using the wrong test module: you need `supertest`, not `superagent`.
Just install the `supertest` module, change the `require` line, and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Look at this video on youtube : watch?v=E9Fmewoe5L4 around 7:45

Comment: I change superagent with supertest and I got the same error.

Comment: Try commenting the line `var expect = require('Chai').expect` - it could be that the `expect` built into `supertest` is confused with the other.

Comment: If I comment that line i got a `ReferenceError: expect is not defined` everywhere.